# Exclude select duplication

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table: **prov_dl**

```
| ID | Code     | Value |
+----+----------+-------+
| 2  | PRC      | 0,1701|
| 2  | Stad     | 3     |
```

Data is stored in this form, that is,
there are several entries by code
You need to pull the data in this form:

```
  | ID | Stadya   | Percent   |
  +----+----------+-----------+
  | 2  | 3        | 0,1701    |
```

I try this:

```
select id,
case when code='Stad' then Value  end Stadya,
case when code='PRC'  then  Value end Percent  
from prov_dl

| ID | Stadya   | Percent|
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  |          | 0,1701 |
| 2  |   3      |        |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use max()

```
    select id,
    max(case when code='Stad' then Value  end) as Stadya,
    max(case when code='PRC'  then  Value end) as Percent  
    from prov_dl group by id
```